# External plugins do not not accessible in scene object after load

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to use external plugins in Phaser, but they do not appear in scene object after load.

I am trying to use external plugins in Phaser like this:
In preload:

```
> scene.load.scenePlugin({
> key: 'AnimatedTiles',
> url: './node_modules/phaser-animated-tiles-phaser3.5/dist/AnimatedTiles.min.js',
> sceneKey: 'animatedTiles'
>         });
(I have tried several urls here)
Then
In create:
> console.log(this);
> this.animatedTiles.init(my_new_map);
```

And I get an error:[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPKx0.png)
scene object does not contain animatedTiles method...
But I have tried to print whole object and it contain in in plugins list (2).

The same issue I see with others plugins.
I have tried to execute same code putting it in one of the Phaser examples for "Plugins" - and it worked just fine...
Don't know what I a missing here.

I have also tried to load the tileAnimation plugin in global game config, but import like this:

```
> import AnimatedTiles from './node_modules/phaser-animated-tiles-phaser3.5/dist/AnimatedTiles.min.js';
```

gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: AnimatedTiles"

Comment: Well, from where are you loading your phaser game? the js file for the plugin will be also served from the webserver, so the easy solution would be to copy it into the website folder to the `phaser.min.js` an use that url, but wihtout knowing your project strucute it is hard to say.

Comment: Thanks! I have found my mistake: I made my preload static, so load plugin failed....